# Error loading available metrics! -- Prometheus

Tags: amazon-ec2, prometheus, grafana, monitoring

I was having a Grafana Monitoring Server with Prometheus as the data source. It was having a volume of much larger size than the capacity that was being used. In order to do the cost-cutting I decided to create a new Monitoring Server with the same configurations, but a smaller volume attached this time, and migrate all the data to the new server. I made all the required installations in the new server, Grafana was up and running in the port 3000, and Prometheus was up and running in the port 9090. Node exporters were also running and accessible. In order to restore the prometheus data present in the old server, I copied all the chunk files present at the location /var/lib/prometheus of the old server to the same path of the new server. After successful migration of the data, I am facing the following issues.

1. Prometheus is displaying the error message, "Error loading available metrics!".
2. .tmp files are getting created in the var/lib/prometheus directory of the new server.
3. Grafana is only showing the monitoring graphs from the time the new server is running. Old graphs are not being shown even though all the chunk files are successfully migrated.

Can anyone please tell me what is the issue and how it can get fixed?
Thanks in advance.